# docker image rm command doesn't work with hanging

Tags: docker

Disk usages of some of my servers are 100%, so I'm trying to remove unusing docker images to get some disk space.

Other than one server, docker image rm command worked fine.

But for a certain server, the command doesn't work.

```
USER@HOST:/home1:> docker rmi DOCKER_IMAGE_ID --force
```

Nothing happens after this command, and the command doesn't exit.

I added `-debug` option, but it's the same, no information printed.

`docker ps` command works well.

How can I resolve this?

Or, is there a way to remove a docker image by finding a corresponding file and run `rm SOME_FILE`?

Comment: I know nothing about `docker`, I guess removing an image involves removing (unlinking) some file(s). In general depending on the filesystem, its mount options and few other factors unlinking a file may or may not be fast. I mean `rm` or whatever may not or may stall. "Nothing happens after this command, and the command doesn't exit" may mean you're not patient enough. E.g. I'm using Btrfs where unlinking a large file can be quite slow, unless the file survives in the filesystem (file in use or link count still greater than zero). Does the certain server differ when it comes to the filesystem?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski No, all the servers have the same filesystems. Follwoing your advice, I'm running the command again and waiting with patience... Any other advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For images the command is `docker rmi imagename/id`.

For containers the command is `docker rm containername/id`.

Comment: I'm aware of the commands. I mean `docker rmi` command hangs. The command doesn't work in a particular server, and I want to find the reason.

Comment: Does the image have multiple tags? Try using the `rmi` command with each tag as a parameter, for all tags. Removing the last tag should also remove the image. Which OS for the problem server?

Comment: I'm on CentOS 7. Is there a difference between using `rmi` with IMAGE_ID and with REPO:TAG? Both result the same though.

Answer (score 0):

If it's hanging, that's either a bug in the docker engine or underlying host.

If it's the docker engine itself that's hanging, then checking logs of the engine may help. With systemd, you can pull those up with journalctl:

```
sudo journalctl -u docker
```

To debug further into the Go stack, you can force a stack trace to be output with:

```
sudo kill -SIGUSR1 $(pidof dockerd)
```

Those logs will be written to `/var/run/docker/`.

If it's the Linux host itself that's having issues, like a failing drive, then checking logs in `/var/log`, and the output of `dmesg` can help identify a potential cause.

Of course the easy answer is to start with turning it off and back on again, restarting the docker engine with:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: With `sudo journalctl -u docker` command, I can see that the most recent log is written on Feb 24, and it is 
`Feb 24 04:32:58 HOST dockerd[18977]: time="2021-02-24T04:32:58.109635778+09:00" level=error msg="failed to process event" container=XXXX error="open /var/lib/docker/containers/XXXX/.tmp-config.v2.json239865109: no space left on device"`
Could you give me more hint?

Comment: @yoon I'm not there at your machine to run the commands to give more details. The log you've shown indicates you ran out of disk space on that position, either bytes or inodes. Though it could also be an application bug or a security setting on the host.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen docker hang in this way when it should fail with an error like:

`Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to remove repository reference "<image name>" (must force) - container <container_id> is using its referenced image <image_id>`

Try: `docker rm <container_id>` if you know of a container using that image, or `docker container prune` (with care) to remove all stopped containers, then `docker rmi <image_name>` again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).